# iOS 9: Core Data with iCloud: hang on addPersistentStoreWithType

Tags: ios, core-data

I have added iCloud support to my Core Data. When I add something to the database, close the app and try to open it again the app does not start, it hangs on my launch screen and in the console I see two information. First that it tries to connect to sqlite database file located at .../CoreDataUbiquitySupport/... and second is this

```
CoreData: sql: pragma journal_mode=delete
```

I think it happens only on simulator.

What does it mean? What is wrong?

It hangs on addPersistentStoreWithType function and after few minutes the function returns with the exception

```
Error adding persistent store to coordinator: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134090 "(null)" UserInfo={NSSQLiteErrorDomain=5, NSUnderlyingException=error during SQL execution : The database operation timed out after 240.00 seconds.
```

Here is how I add persistent store:

```
let options = [
        NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true,
        NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
        NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey: "AppCloudStore"
    ]

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
        do {
            self.store = try self.storeCoordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType,
                configuration: nil,
                URL: storeURL,
                options: options)

            self.initialized = true
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be with using `journal_mode`. After I removed it or changed the mode to `WAL`, I no longer had a locking issue. (This is using iOS 9.1 on an actual device, and not using iCloud for the store.)

You can see it is accessing the `fcntl` function (or sometimes in the `sqlite3.dylib`) if you pause the program during the hang (or rather the polling/infinite loop; mine was at 100% CPU during that time).